# No bclfastq found on path

Tags: paths

I tried to run bcl2fastq, but it said `[error] No bcl2fastq found on path`.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestion!

Best,

Yue

```
    li@li-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:~$ bcl2fastq --help
    BCL to FASTQ file converter
    bcl2fastq v2.20.0.422
    Copyright (c) 2007-2017 Illumina, Inc.

    Usage:
      bcl2fastq [options]






    li@li-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:~$ cellranger mkfastq --id=tiny-bcl  --run=cellranger-tiny-bcl-1.2.0  --csv=cellranger-tiny-bcl-simple-1.2.0.csv
    /home/li/opt/cellranger-3.1.0/cellranger-cs/3.1.0/bin
    cellranger mkfastq (3.1.0)
           Copyright (c) 2019 10x Genomics, Inc.  All rights reserved.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Martian Runtime - '3.1.0-v3.2.3'
    2020-02-11 20:16:39 [jobmngr] WARNING: configured to use 21GB of local memory, but only 19.0GB is currently available.
    2020-02-11 20:16:39 [runtime] Reattaching in local mode.
    Serving UI at http://li-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:39889?auth=ECJkP0tXgwBHrQwqlcZBN1UtFck0Of4F83ahq6jb0OU

    2020-02-11 20:16:39 [runtime] (reset-partial)   ID.tiny-bcl.MAKE_FASTQS_CS.MAKE_FASTQS.MAKE_FASTQS_PREFLIGHT.fork0.chnk0
    2020-02-11 20:16:39 [runtime] (reset-partial)   ID.tiny-bcl.MAKE_FASTQS_CS.MAKE_FASTQS.MAKE_FASTQS_PREFLIGHT_LOCAL.fork0.chnk0
    2020-02-11 20:16:39 [runtime] Found orphaned local stage: ID.tiny-bcl.MAKE_FASTQS_CS.MAKE_FASTQS.MAKE_FASTQS_PREFLIGHT
    2020-02-11 20:16:39 [runtime] Found orphaned local stage: ID.tiny-bcl.MAKE_FASTQS_CS.MAKE_FASTQS.MAKE_FASTQS_PREFLIGHT_LOCAL

    [error] No bcl2fastq found on path. demux requires bcl2fastq v2.17 or greater for RTA version: 1.18.66.4
```

Comment: The problem is that `$PATH` is defined differently in terminal and "`Martian`" environments. Check the `cellranger` documents for `$PATH` definition. In the terminal, `type -p bcl2fastq` will show where `bcl2fastq` actually is. Consider making a soft link `man ln` from there to a directory on `cellpath`'s `$PATH`

Comment: @waltinator  Thank you so much for your great help!